# Can I have partial classes in nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I am building a `nuget` package that will be shared across many projects in the enterprise. It's essentially Entity Framework Model. At some point these classes were scaffolded from the database and the classes that were generated were all defined as partial (all examples are for illustration purposes only):

```
public partial class Customer { ... }
public partial class Order { ... }
```

Some projects took advantage of this `partial` and developed additional functions that are beyond what database cares for:

```
public partial class Customer {
   // get distance from the office to customer home
   public decimal Distance { get { ... } }
}
```

Which allows using this calculated value in LINQ statements:

```
from c in Customer where Distance < 100 select c
```

But now that the "core" set of classes are in nuget package, the classes are no longer partial. Is there a way to force nuget to respect `partial` attribute? I realize that it's too tight coupling; but it would greatly simplify transition from "embedded" model to nuget

Comment: I don't understand your question, when you build the project where the two partial class are, they are merged. What you want to do after ?

Comment: no, they are not - if one partial class is in nuget package (obviously, they *were*, when it was `Models` directory inside the project itself). That's exactly what I am try to achieve: merge to partial classes - one from the project, and one from nuget package.

Comment: I am almost sure of one thing, partial class, in order to work the way they were created must be in the same project and in the same namespace.

Comment: From msdn All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

Comment: in other words, what I want to do is impossible. :( OK, thanks

Comment: Is extension methods could be OK to you ?

Comment: @Felix: Yes, but as dbraillon said you can use extension methods. Or Inheritance of course. Partials were made for autogenerated code only, so the generator wouldn't override user's additions which are in a separate file. It is not a way to perform **ducktyping** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing extending a class functions in OOP is performed via inheritance. Extensionmethods look like member variables but in really they are just syntactic sugar for static (utility) methods

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C# you can not take advantage of partial mechanic to split the definition of a class into different assembly.

[Please see msdn explanation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

What about extensions ? Define your method in an extension class with your methods in the same namespace.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, extensions will work fine - but it will complicate the transition. Oh, well. Got to do it...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its not possible. addition to the answer of @dbraillon

partials are turned into whole classes when the compiler compiles your project. so there is no notion of `partial classes` in a dll.

So:

```
public partial class MyPartial {
   public int FieldA;
}

public partial class MyPartial {
   public int FieldB;
}
```

becomes the following when compiled:

```
public class MyPartial {
   public int FieldA;
   public int FieldB;
}
```